# Can a raspberry pi get the video feed of another through a NFS server between the two?

Tags: python, opencv, nfs

For my project, I need to get the feed (preferably simultaneousely) of 2 pi cameras (one on each pi 4).

As of now, both are communicating through ssh over wifi. It's very slow, not reliable and very complicated to get the feed of the second pi into a kivy app.

I intend to create a NFS server between the 2 through Ethernet.
First, can one of them still access Internet over wifi?
And, can I access to the second camera with opencv?

```
# camera connected to the first raspberry
cam_1 = cv.VideCapture(0)
# camera connected to the second raspberry
cam_2 = cv.VideoCapture(1) # can I do that?
```

I also saw I could replace `0` with `/dev/video0`. If it's possible to access the second camera, which path would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1: Networking**

You should be able to directly connect two Pis together with an Ethernet cable for high-speed data transfers between them. In that scenario the Pis should still have internet access over Wi-Fi in addition to being able to talk directly over Ethernet.

After connecting the Ethernet, each Pi needs a static IP address for its Ethernet adapter. You should be able to configure this through [`dhcpcd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dhcpcd) by running `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf` from the terminal. The following configuration options should be added

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.14.X/24
```

where X is 1 on the first Pi and X is 2 on the second Pi. Press CTRL-X, Y, Enter to save and exit. (Note that the 14 can be changed if it conflicts with some other IP address.) After rebooting each Pi should be able to ping the other on its 192.168.14.X address.

**Part 2: Cameras**

There's not really a practical way to share generic `/dev/` devices over a network connection. Each class of device is unique and tends to have specific ways of dealing with sharing it over a network. For a video camera you'd usually use network streaming. The most convenient way to do that would be to run an RTSP stream on one Pi and open that stream with OpenCV on the second Pi.

To [stream video](https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/how-to/stream-live-video-raspberry-pi) from the camera on a Pi, make sure VLC is installed then run:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 800 -h 600 -fps 12  | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8080/}' :demux=h264
```

from a terminal. The arguments for raspivid can be tweaked to change resolution (-w for width and -h height) and frame rate (-fps).

The video stream [can be opened from Python/OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891936/rtsp-stream-and-opencv-python) using the code:

```
cam_2 = cv.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.14.2:8080/")
```

**Part 3: Other thoughts**

If your application is particularly sensitive to Latency, video over a network may not be ideal. There may be some [slightly more complicated ways](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=263050) of dealing improving latency if a little latency is still OK.

Alternatively, using the [Raspberry Pi 4 Compute Module](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/compute-module-4/) with a [Compute Module 4 IO Board], two cameras can be hooked up to the same Pi, completely eliminating the need for networking.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to share the /home folder of the second pi over NFS. I'll try to share its /dev as well. Else I'll try your streaming solution.

Comment: Can you say where the `out.h264` part of the URL comes from please in the line `cam_2 = cv.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.14.2:8080/out.h264")`

Comment: Good spot, the `/out.h264` in the URI was left over from some other code. A VLC RTSP stream is accessible just from the root of the URI. I've edited the answer to correct this.